# Would the Intel SHA extensions help in creating SHA1 collisions?

Tags: collision-resistance, sha-1

Would the Intel SHA extensions help in creating SHA1 collisions? AMD Ryzen and EPYC supports them.

Answer (score 3):

If you break the attack into two phases, like in the [SHAttered paper](https://shattered.io/static/shattered.pdf), it may help the first phase. The researchers say that they used a CPU cluster for the first phase; the more expensive second phase used a GPU cluster.

> ...from an attacker’s point of view, it may
>   seem best to implement the attack on a CPU in order to be able to claim a better attack
>   complexity. However, a GPU being far more powerful, it is actually much more efficient
>   to run it on the latter: the attack of [[18]](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-662-47989-6_30) takes only a bit more than four days to run on
>   a single GTX 970, which is much less than the estimated 150 days it would take using a
>   single quad-core CPU.

The trade-off is that GPUs may be more difficult to program, but on the plus side, they are more cost-effective.